# How to output array of numbers by setInterval Math.floor Math.random

Tags: arrays, math, random, setinterval

I have multiple HTML elements `<h2> and </b>` with the classname: `randomgen`.

The function `generateRandomNumber` outputs one random number between 1 and 100 to each element:

```
function generateRandomNumber(min_value, max_value) {

    var random_number = Math.random() * (100 - 1) + 1;
    return Math.floor(random_number);
}

document.getElementsByClassName("randomgen")[0].innerHTML = generateRandomNumber();
```

Would it be possible to output multiple `generateRandomNumber();` in an array, instead of identifying each [x] for the class `randomgen`?

```
setInterval(function () {

    document.getElementsByClassName("randomgen")[0].innerHTML = generateRandomNumber();
    document.getElementsByClassName("randomgen")[1].innerHTML = generateRandomNumber();
    document.getElementsByClassName("randomgen")[2].innerHTML = generateRandomNumber();
    document.getElementsByClassName("randomgen")[3].innerHTML = generateRandomNumber();
    document.getElementsByClassName("randomgen")[4].innerHTML = generateRandomNumber();
    document.getElementsByClassName("randomgen")[5].innerHTML = generateRandomNumber();
    document.getElementsByClassName("randomgen")[6].innerHTML = generateRandomNumber();
    document.getElementsByClassName("randomgen")[7].innerHTML = generateRandomNumber();
    document.getElementsByClassName("randomgen")[8].innerHTML = generateRandomNumber();
    document.getElementsByClassName("randomgen")[9].innerHTML = generateRandomNumber();
    document.getElementsByClassName("randomgen")[10].innerHTML = generateRandomNumber();
    document.getElementsByClassName("randomgen")[11].innerHTML = generateRandomNumber();
    document.getElementsByClassName("randomgen")[12].innerHTML = generateRandomNumber();
    document.getElementsByClassName("randomgen")[13].innerHTML = generateRandomNumber();
    document.getElementsByClassName("randomgen")[14].innerHTML = generateRandomNumber();
    document.getElementsByClassName("randomgen")[15].innerHTML = generateRandomNumber();
    document.getElementsByClassName("randomgen")[16].innerHTML = generateRandomNumber();
    document.getElementsByClassName("randomgen")[17].innerHTML = generateRandomNumber();
    document.getElementsByClassName("randomgen")[18].innerHTML = generateRandomNumber();
    document.getElementsByClassName("randomgen")[19].innerHTML = generateRandomNumber();
    document.getElementsByClassName("randomgen")[20].innerHTML = generateRandomNumber();
    document.getElementsByClassName("randomgen")[21].innerHTML = generateRandomNumber();
    document.getElementsByClassName("randomgen")[22].innerHTML = generateRandomNumber();
    document.getElementsByClassName("randomgen")[23].innerHTML = generateRandomNumber();

}, 8000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand where you hit the problem. [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) and you certainly can iterate over it in a generic way. The code like this should work (I use one-time `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` to not waste CPU of the people who view this answer)

```js
function generateRandomNumber(min_value, max_value) {

    var random_number = Math.random() * (100 - 1) + 1;
    return Math.floor(random_number);
}


setTimeout(function() {
   var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("randomgen");
   for(var el of elems) {
      el.innerHTML = generateRandomNumber();
   }

}, 2000);
```

```html
<h2 class="randomgen">
#1
</h2>
<h2 class="randomgen">
#2
</h2>
<h2 class="randomgen">
#3
</h2>
```

Comment: Thank you, it was the generic way to iterate the html elements I was trying to solve. It works perfectly!